# Unity crashes when using native code

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, plugins, unity-game-engine

So I try to communicate c# code in unity and objective c code in Xcode.
Here is my code:

text.h

```
extern "C" {
int textTotexture(int hello,int world);
}
```

text.mm

```
int textTotexture(int hello,int world){
NSString *myString =[[NSString alloc] init];
NSSize size = [myString sizeWithAttributes:0];
NSImage* newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: size]; 
[newImage lockFocus]; 

/* if you have a second image you're going to overlay on top of the first, do the same except use NSCompositeSourceOver as the operation */
//NSRect myRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,size.width,size.height);

//[myString drawInRect:myRect withAttributes:0]; 
[newImage unlockFocus];
//NSData *imageData = [newImage TIFFRepresentation];
//NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
//NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
//imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:imageProps];
//int len = [imageData length];
//memcpy(data, [imageData bytes], len);
return hello+world;
}
```

calling function:

```
[DllImport("CubePlugin")]
public static extern int textTotexture(int s, int w);
Debug.Log(textTotexture(1,2));
```

The basic communication is fine as debug log returns 3. but as soon as I add functional code in, the unity just crashes. I suspect some of the native code just doesn't run to the end.

I just found out the issue occurs when I add lock focus and lose focus back in. What shall I do to avoid doing this but achieve my goal?

Comment: When you say "it crashes" what actually happens?  EXC_BAD_ACCESS?  Objective-C exception?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, when i say crash i mean it just freezes and i have to force quit the unity

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock.  Are you running this code on the main thread?   If not, you have big problems because the Cocoa drawing API is not thread safe.

Comment: i have no idea how the thread is handled. i simply put the calling function in start() and run..

Comment: In the Objective-C part: `if ([NSThread currentThread] != [NSThread mainTHread]) { /* log it */ }` and if it is not the main thread, some redesign might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

its not obvious how your are handling your class "text" but you can try this: (I am writing without editor so there might be typos)

```
@implementation text
//.... 
-(int)textToTexture:(int)A andValue:(int)B
{
   int result = 0;
   // do stuff
   return result
}
@end

static text* myObject = nil;

extern "C"{
   int textToTexture(int a, int b)
  {
     if(myObject == nil)
         myObject = [[text alloc] init];

     return [myObject textToTexture:a andValue:b];
  }
}
```

inside your C# file

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
public static extern int textTotexture(int a, int b);
```

then call the function